# Weather in Australia (Melbourne) summer, winter?

Tags: australia, weather-and-climate, clothing, melbourne

I will go Australia in couple of days for higher education.

I searched for the weather in Australia (Melbourne) but I could not get exact information about the current season (summer or hot) in Australia.  So can anyone help me to know what the weather is right now so I can buy my clothes according to need?

Comment: i checked that and i know now a days it is cold but, but i was confused because some time its s end of any season. weather forecasting do not tell season, i think i'm right here. can you tell me right now is summer or winter ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melbourne#Climate (scroll down to the table)

Comment: i got more precise info here. (in few lines , described good) http://www.melbourne.vic.gov.au/AboutMelbourne/MelbourneProfile/Pages/Melbourneweatherandclimate.aspx

Comment: @coder right now it's summer :) (source: I lived in Melbourne until June, and also science).  It's the opposite of the northern hemisphere.

Comment: Make sure to bring extra clothing since Australia is expensive. You need to have all type of weather clothing since the temperature will fluctuate. I would definitely recommend going to somewhere like REI that has travel clothing. The lighter and waterproof type jackets are a good idea. There is nothing worse than not having a rain jacket when you need one.

Comment: I grew up in Melbourne, lived there for 13 years - in summer it gets nice and warm, dry heat mainly. In winter, you may as well be living in London it's grey, and it gets rainy/cold.

Agree with @IeiJonGroom - aus is expensive, so buy up clothes before hand and just stick to buying the basics

Comment: If you want to know the current weather for any place just type in "Melbourne weather" into your browser URL bar or into Google.

Comment: Don't forget that Melbourne doesn't have seasons in the traditional sense ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's currently summer.  Seasons in Australia are the opposite of the northern hemisphere, so if it's winter in the northern hemisphere, it's summer here.

I lived in Melbourne last year, and even when it is summer (and it gets really, really hot) cool changes can come through fast, and temperatures can drop. Bring summer clothes, but you'd be mistaken to not bring one jacket for those rare weather swings.

Answer (score 2):

For travel weather, I like to use weatherspark.com.  Here is a link for the average weather in Melbourne: http://weatherspark.com/averages/34069/Melbourne-Victoria-Australia

The average temperatures and rainfall, taken from that page, are shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's worth adding summer, given the actual question is he wasn't sure what the season currently is...